# Cannot import xls/xlsx files

Tags: php, excel, import

I am importing an excel file into MySQL using PHP. The following code works for csv files but not for xls/xlsx file formats.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Import Excel to MySQL using PHP </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body style="padding-top:50px;">

<div class="container"><!-- container class is used to centered  the body of the browser with some decent width-->
    <div class="row"><!-- row class is used for grid system in Bootstrap-->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><!--col-md-4 is used to create the no of colums in the grid also use for medimum and large devices-->
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Import here</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form method="post" action="import.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="file" name="file"/>
                            </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_file" value="Submit"/>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Import.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
/*
Developer: Ehtesham Mehmood
Site:      PHPCodify.com
Script:    Import Excel to MySQL using PHP and Bootstrap
File:      import.php
*/

// Including database connections
require_once 'db_con.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit_file"]))
{
 $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

 $file_open = fopen($file,"r");
 while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)
 {
  $employee_name = $csv[0];
  $employee_designation = $csv[1];
  $employee_salary = $csv[2];

  $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO employee(employee_name,employee_designation,employee_salary) VALUES(:employee_name,:employee_designation,:employee_salary)");

  $stmt->bindparam(':employee_name', $employee_name);
  $stmt->bindparam(':employee_designation', $employee_designation);
  $stmt->bindparam(':employee_salary', $employee_salary);
  $stmt->execute();
 }
}

echo "Imported Successfully";
?>
```

Comment: You are using this is only CSV file. But for XLS files, there is a different method.

Comment: I improved the title, moved the question to the top for more visibility, and cleaned up the grammar and repetitive nature

Answer (score 0):

Different examples of **xls** files in PHP. Here I am attaching code sample.

Parsing Rows:

```
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('File_For_Import.xlsx');
        list($num_cols, $num_rows) = $xlsx->dimension();
        $f = 0;
        foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $r) {
            // Ignore the inital name row of excel file
            if ($f == 0) {
                $f++;
                continue;
            }
            //sample column-names for your understanding.  
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i++) {
                if ($i == 0) 
                    $data['employee_name'] = $r[$i];
                else if($i == 1) 
                     $data['employee_designation'] = $r[$i];  
                else if ($i == 2)
                     $data['employee_salary'] = $r[$i];    
             //write code according to your DB.   
            }
            $data['class_id'] = $this->input->post('class_id');
            $this->db->insert('student', $data);
            //print_r($data);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your commend. i got this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SimpleXLSX' not found in

Comment: Have you imported SimpleXLSX class?

Comment: yep but again an error Catchable fatal error: Object of class SimpleXLSX could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

That is because Excel files, xls or xlsx, are not CSV files.

There are 3 different file formats that requires 3 different approaches.
You need to find an Excel library for PHP, like [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com) for example:

```
$workbook = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");
//for xls file
$rows = $workbook->easy_ReadXLSActiveSheet_AsList("file.xls");
//or 
//for xlsx file
$rows = $workbook->easy_ReadXLSXActiveSheet_AsList("file.xlsx");
for ($rowIndex=0; $rowIndex<$rows->size(); $rowIndex++)
{
    $row = $rows->elementAt($rowIndex);
    $employee_name = $row->elementAt(0);
    $employee_designation = $row->elementAt(1);
    $employee_salary = $row->elementAt(2);

    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO employee(employee_name,employee_designation,employee_salary) VALUES(:employee_name,:employee_designation,:employee_salary)");

    $stmt->bindparam(':employee_name', $employee_name);
    $stmt->bindparam(':employee_designation', $employee_designation);
    $stmt->bindparam(':employee_salary', $employee_salary);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

More about [importing Excel file into MySQL using PHP](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/import-excel-to-mysql.html).

Comment: thanks for your commend but an error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in

Comment: You need to add the extension for .NET framework in php server https://www.easyxls.com/manual/troubleshooting/class-com-not-found.html